# jqgrid upload multiple files with different file ids using ajaxFileUpload

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, multiple-file-upload

I am using jqgrid, and I need to upload files from two different inputs using one ajax file upload call. I can upload one file using the fileElementId, but is there any way to upload two files simultaneously?

```
function uploadFiles(dfcId) {
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: '/DigitalFileCabinet/UploadFile',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        secureuri: true,
        async: false,
        data: { id: dfcId },
        fileElementId: "file1",
        success: function (response, status) {
            //success code
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            if (status === 'success')
                return;
            else
                return alert('Failed to upload PDF!');
        }
    });
};
```

I have tried the following method, which uses an array to get two file elements at once and upload, but it didn't work.
https://www.programmersought.com/article/194562558/

Comment: See if this plugin support more id's set in option **fileElementId: "file1"**, alternatively you can create two function like your uploadFiles and call them one after other

Comment: @TonyTomov Thank you for the comment, but if we use it like that, we are making two server calls; I am searching for a way to send in one single call.